# How to validate radio buttons in a b-form-radio-group in vuejs

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-vue

I have a b-form-radio-group of radio buttons, how can I validate them as one of them must be checked?

Here is a div of b-form-radio-group inside the b-modal

```
<b-modal id="manageQuantity" title="Manage Quantity" @ok="updateQuantity">
<div class="radio-button">
            <b-form-group
              id="quantityOption"
              label-cols-sm="3"
              label="Option :"
              label-for="input-horizontal"
            >
              <b-form-radio-group
                id="quantityOption"
                class="individual-button"
                buttons
                button-variant="outline-secondary"
                v-model="form.quantityOption"
                :options="quantityOptions"
              ></b-form-radio-group>
            </b-form-group>
            </div>
</b-modal>
```

When I click "OK" button the b-modal should warn me if I did not select any of the radio button.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `state` property. You also can use the `b-form-invalid-feedback` `b-form-valid-feedback` slots for the messages:

```
<b-form-radio-group
    id="quantityOption"
    class="individual-button"
    buttons
    button-variant="outline-secondary"
    v-model="form.quantityOption"
    :options="quantityOptions"
    :state="state"
>
    <b-form-invalid-feedback :state="state">Please select one</b-form-invalid-feedback>
    <b-form-valid-feedback :state="state">Thank you</b-form-valid-feedback>
</b-form-radio-group>



....
data(){
    return{
        form:{
            quantityOption: null            
        }
    }
}
...
computed: {
    state() {
        return Boolean(this.form.quantityOption)    
    }
}
...
```

You could find more in the documentation: https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/components/form-radio/#contextual-state-with-feedback-example

Answer (score 0):

In your `updateQuantity` method you can check if your `quantityOption`is set or not.

You could also implement Andriy's answer for a more visual representation, but you still need the check in the event to make sure it's set or not.

```
<div>
  <b-btn v-b-modal.modal>Open Modal</b-btn>
  <b-modal id="modal" @ok="updateQuantity">
    <b-form-radio-group
    buttons
    button-variant="outline-secondary"
    v-model="form.quantityOption"
    :options="quantityOptions"
    ></b-form-radio-group>
  </b-modal>
</div>



<script>
  data() {
    return {
      form: { quantityOption: null },
      quantityOptions: [ 
        {value: 1, text: '1' },
        {value: 2, text: '2' },
        {value: 3, text: '3' }
      ]
    }
  },
  methods: {
    updateQuantity(event) {
      if(!this.form.quantityOption){
        alert('Please select one of the options first')
        event.preventDefault()
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```